# how to write a regex for the following scenario?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I like to write a regex which has to satisfy all these examples

without using ^ like

```
[^ i|like|to|drink][\w+](\s*)(\w*)
```

Regex: ?

**Example 1:**

```
sentence = i like to drink black tea
output = black tea
```

**Example 2:**

```
sentence: drink tea
output : tea
```

**Example 3:**

```
sentence = drink pomegranate juice
output = pomegranate juice
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern `(?<=\bdrink\b)\s*(.*$)` --> `Lookbehind`

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = ["i like to drink black tea", "drink tea", "drink pomegranate juice"]
for sentence in data:
    m = re.search(r"(?<=\bdrink\b)\s*(.*$)", sentence)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
black tea
tea
pomegranate juice
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. how to extend the above regex to handle the case like i would like to have tea?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `[^ i|like|to|drink][\w+](\s*)(\w*)` uses a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match matches any character that is not in the character class.

I think you meant to use a grouping structure using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with the or `|` but that will not give you the desired matches.

It seems you want what comes after `drink`. In that case you don't need a lookbehind but only a capturing group where your value is in the first group:

```
\bdrink\b\s+(.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fdBPSM/1)

If there can be multiple words before what you want to match you could use an alternation:

```
\b(?:drink|have)\b\s+(.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE74eE/1)

Another option could be to split on the word "drink" between word boundaries `\b`

```
import re
strings = ["i like to drink black tea", "drink tea", "drink pomegranate juice", "testdrinktest"]
for str in strings:
    parts = re.split(r"\bdrink\b", str)
    if len(parts) > 1:
        print(parts[1])
```

Result:

```
 black tea
 tea
 pomegranate juice
```

Answer (score 0):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/hPEOZl/1) might help you to do so by simply creating two capturing group:

```
(drink)\s(.+)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Code

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(drink)\s(.+)"

test_str = ("i like to drink black tea\n"
    "drink tea\n"
    "drink pomegranate juice\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
Match 1 was found at 10-25: drink black tea
Group 1 found at 10-15: drink
Group 2 found at 16-25: black tea
Match 2 was found at 26-35: drink tea
Group 1 found at 26-31: drink
Group 2 found at 32-35: tea
Match 3 was found at 36-59: drink pomegranate juice
Group 1 found at 36-41: drink
Group 2 found at 42-59: pomegranate juice
```